# Could this piece of code be harmful ?

Tags: .net, mac-address, network-access-control

I just wrote these 2 functions in `C#.net` and it can get any user's system IP and MAC address. Isn't this harmful since I got help from microsoft documentation. Could these lead to potential damage or could be labeled as illegal ?

```
public string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
        return localIP;
    }

    private string GetMacAddress()
    {
        string macAddresses = string.Empty;

        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        return macAddresses;
    }
```

Comment: Any code can be considered damaging, and might potentially become illegal. For example, `perl -e "fork while fork" &` will potentially cause denial of service against anyone who runs it. In some territories, this might be illegal. In others, since someone would have to specifically run it, the code is fine. In some regions, IP addresses may be considered personally identifiable, in which case local data protection laws might kick in. In general, any function you write is legal _as long as you only run it on machines you own_ - beyond that, it's entirely down to local laws.

Comment: Welcome on Security SE. Please avoid to cross-post [the very same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881093/how-this-code-be-used) on multiple SE websites. And by the way getting your own IP address is no more illegal than getting your own phone number.

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf what If secretly embed it in any app's code and it regularly transmits the IP address and MAC of that user ?

Comment: would be a very bad network if nothing could communicate with each other. all you have is a phone book!

Comment: Your code snippets get the IP and MAC address of the local system (where the code is executed). Not "any user". This isn't different from running `ipconfig /all`

Answer (score 3):

An IP number is very comparable to a phone number. By default this is a public information available in any public directory and is necessary to establish a communication.

However there are tons of way to exploit even public information in illegal ways.

So the real determinant here is not the fact that you are collecting the local IP and MAC address, but the purpose you have behind it.

Comment: Pretty much this. What are you planning on doing with it?

Comment: I think your final sentance - if generalised - could be applied to most things discussed here lol